# Cython vs Python : same function different results

Tags: python, function, cython

I have the same function in Python and Cython ... the problem is they rerturn different results ??

What could be the reason ?

Python version gives more correct results.

> Python

```
def convolution(a,b):
    n = a.size
    rv = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    # prods = np.zeros(n,dtype=hsdp.TYPE)
    for i in range(n) :
        prods_sum = 0
        for j in range(n) :
            prods_sum += a[j] * b[(i-j)%n]
        rv[i] = prods_sum#np.sum(prods)

    return rv
```

> Cython

```
def cy_convolution(np.float64_t[:] a, np.float64_t[:] b): 
    cdef int n,i,j,ix
    cdef np.float64_t prods_sum
    cdef np.float64_t[:] rv_view

    n = a.size
    rv = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
    rv_view  = rv
    for i in range(n) :
        prods_sum = 0
        for j in range(n) :
            ix = (i-j) % n
            prods_sum += a[j] * b[ix]
        rv_view[i] = prods_sum

    return rv
```

---

```
In [9]:  cy_convolution(a,b)                                                                                                                                                 
Out[9]: array([ 0.4 , -0.06, -0.18,  0.42,  0.04, -0.31, -0.27, -0.23,  0.19, -0.03])

In [10]: convolution(a,b)                                                                                                                                               
Out[10]: array([ 0.45,  0.11, -0.29,  0.33,  0.02, -0.25, -0.29, -0.24,  0.18, -0.03])

In [11]: a                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[11]: [-0.57  0.4  -0.28 -0.31 -0.07 -0.03  0.53 -0.17 -0.11 -0.04]

In [12]: b                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[12]: [-0.69 -0.38  0.39  0.11  0.1   0.44  0.01 -0.05 -0.01  0.1 ]

In [14]: a.dtype                                                                                                                                                             
Out[14]: dtype('float64')

In [15]: b.dtype                                                                                                                                                             
Out[15]: dtype('float64')
```

---

```
 # cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False,nonecheck=False,cdivision=True
 # distutils: define_macros=NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, getting identical results (same as your `convolution(a, b)`) in both cases

Comment: Are you using any compiler directives?

Comment: weird ... let me write test script, instead of ipython

Comment: `cdivision=True` makes the difference. Can you try `ix = (n+(i-j)) % n`?

Comment: that was the culprit thanks